# jgit - files not getting added to the github repo

Tags: java, jgit

i tried the jgit to add files to the github repo. Commit is getting created, but the files are not added, In addfilepattern - i tried "." as well. I have commented pull as i am  facing error w.r.t branch - saying branch not found. Below is my code snippet:

```
   Git.cloneRepository().setURI("https://github.com/"+org+"/"+repo+".git").setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).setDirectory(new File(Gitpath)).setCloneAllBranches(true).call();

Git.init().setDirectory(new File(Gitpath)).setInitialBranch("main").call();

var git = Git.open(new File(Gitpath));

//git.pull().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).setRemoteBranchName("main").call();

git.add().setUpdate(true).addFilepattern(directoryName+fileName).call();

git.commit().setMessage("Adding files.").call();

git.push().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).call();
```

Comment: What's the value of `directoryName` and `fileName`? What's your working directory (not be confused with working tree)?

Comment: I have not set a working directory . Please advise if we need to set it and how?      
 String directoryName = "D:/Vk/dev/Github-PoC/"+repo+"/Testing/test";
String fileName = "Testing.txt"

Comment: If we are adding new files, setupdate should be false or should not be set?

Comment: With those values of directory name and file name, your path will be "…/Testing/testTesting.txt" – can you spot the error?

Comment: But with "." also, it didn't work. So, the issue is with setupdate right? Setupdate=true doesn't consider the new files?

Comment: Your file pattern is incorrect, please see my previous comment.

Comment: I am able to commit, push files after removing setupdate.